# Rails prevent error when ActiveRecord association is nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I have a table like "groups" that stores a list of groups that my "users" can belong to. In the User model, this is accomplished with `belongs_to :group`. In my view, I want to display the group name. I'm trying to do that with `@user.group.name`.

The problem is that not every user is assigned to a group, so `@user.group` for example would be `nil`. So, I get a `NoMethodError: undefined method 'name' for nil:NilClass` which is frustrating.

What is the best way to work around this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I typically use [Object#try](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-try) for this:

```
@user.group.try(:name) # returns nil if @user.group is nil
```

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way would be to do something like this:

```
<% if @user.group.present? %>
  <%= @user.group.name %>
 <% end %>
```

However, according to the [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter), a model should only talk to it's immediate association/should not know about its association's methods.

So, ideally, you should do something like this (in your User model):

```
delegate :name, :to => :group, :prefix => true, :allow_nil => true
```

Which you can then access through `@user.group_name`. It will return `nil` if there is no associated group, but will not raise an exception. This is equivalent to

```
def group_name
  group.try(:name)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create a method with a good name, so it would be easy to reuse the code.

```
def is_assigned?
  self.group
end

<% if @user.is_assigned? %>
  ...
<% end %>
```